# Unknown IMAP4 command: 'idle' When Accessing Inbox

Tags: python, imaplib

I am trying to check for new emails in real time. I believe the code below should work but I get an "AttributeError: Unknown IMAP4 command: 'idle'" error. Can anyone see what the issue is?

```
import imaplib
import email

username = "test@xxxxx.com"
password = "xxxxx"

# Connect to the IMAP server
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('mail.xxxxx.com')

# Login to the server
mail.login(username, password)

# Select the INBOX folder
mail.select("INBOX")

# Start listening for new emails
mail.idle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer:

`imaplib` doesn't support `IDLE`. Github issue (from 2011!) for this is still open --> https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/55454

It provides several solutions for this, so I'm not going to reinvent the wheel here (pun intended).

---

### Old answer

I'm going to guess that your specific email server doesn't support the `IDLE` command.

[Quick recap here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) for the `IDLE` command, and note that this is an optional feature.

You can check this using the code below (login to server not needed to check capabilities):

```py
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('mail.xxxxx.com')
print(mail.capabilities)
```

This will output a `tuple[str]` which should look like this:

> ('IMAP4REV1', 'UNSELECT', ***'IDLE'***, 'NAMESPACE', 'QUOTA', 'ID', 'XLIST',
> 'CHILDREN', 'X-GM-EXT-1', 'XYZZY', 'SASL-IR', 'AUTH=XOAUTH2',
> 'AUTH=PLAIN', 'AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN', 'AUTH=OAUTHBEARER')

And note that in the response that I got (from GMail) includes the `IDLE` capability...

Comment: Thanks @Edo. I get the IDLE capability too.

Comment: Looks like `imaplib` itself is the one not supporting `IDLE`, see my updated answer...